# Windows Mobile development in Python

Tags: python, windows-mobile

What is the best way to start developing Windows Mobile Professional applications in Python? Is there a reasonable SDK including an emulator? Is it even possible without doing excessive amount of underlaying Windows API calls for UI for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IronPython and .Net Compact Framework teams work together, Visual Studio may one day support Python for Windows Mobile development out-of-the-box. Unfortunately, [this feature request has been sitting on their issue tracker for ages](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9191)...

Answer (score 9):

### Python CE

Python port for Windows CE (Pocket PC) devices. Intended to be as close to desktop version as possible (console, current directory support, testsuite passed).

[image: Python CE]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/images/python-logo.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 9):

(I used to write customer apps for Windows Mobile.)

Forget about python. Even if it's technically possible:

- your app will be big (you'll have to bundle the whole python runtime with your app)
- your app will use lots of memory (python is a memory hog, relative to C/C++)
- your app will be slow
- you wont find any documentation or discussion groups to help you when you (inevitably) encounter problems

Go with C/C++ (or C#). Visual Studio 2005/2008 have decent tools for those (SDK for winmo built-in, debugging on the emulator or device connected through USB), the best documentation is for those technologies plus there are active forums/discussion groups/mailing lists where you can ask for help.

Comment: also for people that haven't done much/any mobile/embedded development... they need to remeber that speed and memory are big issues.  You are not working on a multi-GHz system that has several GB of RAM.  Most mobiles may have upwards of 400MHz processes and maybe 256MB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this: http://ejr44.blogspot.com/2008/05/python-for-windows-mobile-cab.html

Looks like a complete set of .CAB files to provide Python on Windows Mobile.